# XPath selecting multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file and I want to select title, year and price nodes from all CD's from EU, having the price between 7 and 10. I tried in this way `//CD[contains(COUNTRY,"EU")]` but is showing all the elements from `CD` nodes. how to make an XPath to show just specific elements (TITLE, YEAR and PRICE).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Greatest Hits</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Still got the blues</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="ita">Eros</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">One night only</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Maggie May</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="ita">Romanza</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Black angel</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">For the good times</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Big Willie style</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Soulsville</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">The very best of</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Stop</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Private Dancer</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="dan">Midt om natten</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="ita">Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">The dock of the bay</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Picture book</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Red</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE lang="eng">Unchain my heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
//CD[COUNTRY/text()="EU"]/*[self::TITLE or self::YEAR or self::PRICE]
```

It selects only those `CD`s that have `EU` as `COUNTRY` and then selects all children having the tag name equal to `TITLE` or `YEAR` or `PRICE`.