# xpath: select multiple child element attributes from xml

Tags: xml, xpath, sas

Having trouble getting the desired output... maybe it's not possible but I'm new to XPath selectors.

I have XML like:

```
<submission>
    <component type="X">
        <audit>
            <measures>
                <measure id="xyz">
                    <reported>false</reported>
                    <benefit>false</benefit>
                    <data-elements>
                        <data-element id="rate1">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate2">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate3">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate4">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                    </data-elements>
                </measure>
                <measure id="abc">
                    <reported>false</reported>
                    <benefit>false</benefit>
                    <data-elements>
                        <data-element id="rate5">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate6">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate7">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="rate8">
                            <reportable>false</reportable>
                            <comment/>
                        </data-element>
                    </data-elements>
                </measure>
            </measures>
        </audit>
    </component>
</submission>
```

I'm trying to access the attributes with XPath selectors using a XMLMAP like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SXLEMAP version="1.2">
  <TABLE name="AUDIT">  
    <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">  
       /submission/component/audit/measures/measure
     </TABLE-PATH>

    <COLUMN name="MEASURE" retain="YES">  
      <PATH syntax="XPath">  
         /submission/component/audit/measures/measure@id
        </PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>STRING</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>30</LENGTH>
     </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="RATES">  
      <PATH syntax="XPath">  
       //submission/component/audit/measures/measure/data-elements/data-element/@id
        </PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>STRING</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>20</LENGTH>
     </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="REPORT">  
      <PATH syntax="XPath">  
       /submission/component/audit/measures/measure/data-elements/data-element/reportable
        </PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>STRING</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>20</LENGTH>
     </COLUMN>
```

My output looks like:

```
   MEASURE                           RATES                   REPORT

   xyz                               rate4                   false
   abc                               rate8                   false
```

I want my output to get ALL the rates, not just the last rate, like:

```
   MEASURE                           RATES                   REPORT

   xyz                               rate1                   false
   xyz                               rate2                   false
   xyz                               rate3                   false
   xyz                               rate4                   false
   abc                               rate5                   false
   abc                               rate6                   false
   abc                               rate7                   false
   abc                               rate8                   false
```

Is this possible using XMLMAP or do I need something else?

Thanks in advance for your input!

****edit***********************************************;

Here is a basic SAS program that pulls the xml in and prints the output:

```
* set destination for output *;
LIBNAME DATA '<filepath>';

* set location of xml document and xml_map *;
LIBNAME XFILE XML '<filepath>\stack_example.xml' 
          XMLMAP='<filepath>\stack_import_map.xml';


* check import *;
PROC PRINT DATA= XFILE.AUDIT;
RUN;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I found the following - but none helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457638/xpath-get-nodes-where-child-node-contains-an-attribute  ---- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096435/xpath-selecting-multiple-nodes ---- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320082/how-to-select-multiple-nodes-from-xml-with-xpath

Comment: You're using SAS to import this via an xmlmap?  What version of SAS?

Comment: Yes! I'm using SAS 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out...

In my table path I need to get down to the line level where I want a new observation (row) to start, like:

```
<TABLE name="AUDIT">  
        <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">  
           /submission/component/audit/measures/measure/data-elements/data-element
         </TABLE-PATH>
```

This will now select all the data-elements I want.

Comment: Yep, that sounds exactly like the problem!